# How to save bidirectional maps in a database?

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I want to create a database table where iso2 codes are mapped to their iso3 equivalent, eg:

`DE <-> DEU` for Germany:

```
@Entity
public class LanguageCode {
   @Id
   private String iso2;

   @Id
   private String iso3;

   private String countryName;
}
```

I want to be able to look up both directions:

```
dao.findByIso3("DEU"); //returns DE
dao.findByIso2("DE");  //returns DEU
```

How could I implement this, if possible at all. How could I query for both tables being a primary key?

Also, each iso2 + iso3 codes must be unique.

The problem is: if only iso2 would be `@Id`, I could use `dao.find(iso2)` as the 2-letter code acts as primary key.
BUT if I have a composite key combined of iso2+iso3, I could NOT query it like this as I could only query for the combination.

So I would have to use `SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE iso3 = 'DEU'` which would work of course, but I thought there might be a better approach to directly use primary keys instead of `where` selects?

Comment: What's the concrete problem? You would query this entity like you would suery any other entity: with JPAL or criteria queries.

Comment: Please see my update. My intention is to avoid `where` selects by attribute, but rather select by PK.

Comment: No, there is no better way than using queries. I don't see what you gain by making iso2+iso3 the primary key. You actually lose because 1. you can't use find() to load by iso2 only, 2. you can have several rows with the same iso2 but different iso3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick one of the columns as the PK and make the other one "just" unique:

```
create table language_codes
(
   iso3 text not null primary key,
   iso2 text not null unique, 
   country_name text not null
);
```

The unique column is what is known as an "alternate key".